# Github, How to add/update/delete from same Repo on Multiple Machines

Tags: git, github

I am working on a large project, and have two computers I'll be using to do so. I created the initial project on my iMac, and want portability to work on it with my laptop.

So far I cloned the repo, using:

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

I delete a few folders and go to push to URL of inital repo:

```
 git remote add origin remote repository URL

 git push -u origin master
```

I get an error

```
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
```

I am assuming this is because I deleted some files. So I do

```
git fetch
```

Try again and the same keeps happening. It's going to be a real pain if I cant work on this project on multiple machines. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the remote branch into your current branch by running **git pull**

Comment: I tried that too and got:

'fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories'

Comment: You can use `git pull origin branchname --allow-unrelated-histories` to force the merge to happen.